# Get Substring using Regular Expression Between Two Line Breaks

Tags: regex

I need to pull the address from this block of text using a regular expression. The address is all text on lines 3 and 4 ("Address Line 1" & "Address Line 2").

Here is an example of the block of text I will be running the expression against:

```
"*Company Name*
Contact: Contact Name
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Office Phone: 123-456-7890
Cell Phone:
Fax:
Website: http://www.google.com
Email Us"
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to capture 3rd and 4th lines?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? (How to matching across line breaks varies by engine.)

Comment: The data I'm working with is in a Google Sheet cell. I'm separating out each piece of the data to it's own column (Name, address, phone, etc...). So for the address column, I need to get just the two lines of the address.

**EDIT:** Google uses the re2 engine for the =regextract formula that I need to use. [link](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^\n]*\n){2}(([^\n]*\n){2})
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group 1 .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vG3hL4/2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole lines 3 and 4, you can use the following regex:

```
.*[\s\S].*[\s\S](.*)[\s\S](.*)[\s\S]
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/iK0jI4/1).

The address details are in the 1st and 2nd capture groups. Also, it will be good only if you test individual blocks of text against it (no `g` option here). Actually, without any other boundaries, I doubt there can be another way of capturing address lines properly.